# How can I store spanish characters into my database without losing the characters for display?

Tags: wordpress, special-characters, encode

I have characters that use spanish characters such as in the word `Rosé`. I need to store this into my (wordpress) database and store it so I can display it later. How can I store/encode these characters so I can display the text correctly when needed on the site?

This question is different than the one suggested as this pertains to a Wordpress database. I have limited control over what I can do from a server level with the host. The suggested questions deals with setting up Apache and PHP to a custom level, something that I won't have access to on production.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

You should use UTF8 encoding in your site.

Comment: the database and tables are all UTF8

Comment: If I do `mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8')` it stores the values but the characters are converted incorrectly.

Comment: Have you ser UTF encoding on your site? something like "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >"

Comment: It's not an issue of how it's displayed in the page, it's issue of saving to the database.

Comment: Try this: open your wordpress wp-config.php file and remove this two lines define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8′);
define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);

Comment: Also ensure that your text editor does not save your file with ANSI encoding

Comment: I removed those lines, and I get the same thing: nothing insert to the database. If I use `mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8')` it inserts but the wrong characters are used. If I use `htmlentities` it inserts but anything converted is blank.

Comment: I'm not using the editor. This text is coming from a CSV file.

Comment: For example `Extra Añejo` is being stored and displayed as `A¤ejo` the "ñ" is being encoded wrong.